# Display datepicker on top of the forms's modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I have a custom item edit form and I have a couple of DateTime properties that has to be filled at the bottom of the form (using datepicker):

[image]

So when I click the mini calendar icon to choose the date, it overflows the form and is under the dialog frame:

[image]

Of course, I could just expand the height of the form itself and leave some more blank space at the end, but I would like to show the datepicker "on top" of the whole dialog, something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

I've tried messing around with z-index, but it never overlaps the dialog...

Comment: Please provide your code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is github link that i am using https://github.com/mashmatrix/react-lightning-design-system/blob/master/src/scripts/Datepicker.js

Answer (score -1):

If you want the overflowing text in the div to automatically newline instead of being hidden or making a scrollbar, use the

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

property.